# Jenkins with Maven and npm process fails with EAGAIN error during npm install

Tags: node.js, maven, jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline

So i got my jenkins pipeline setup for a application that uses spring boot as backend and vuejs as frontend. The maven build process builds the frontend first, copies that to the backend and then builds the backend. But during the build of the frontend the process fails ONLY if i run it through the jenkins pipeline. (for other people the same pipeline apparently works on a different machine)

```
[INFO] npm ERR! code EAGAIN
[INFO] npm ERR! syscall spawn sh
[INFO] npm ERR! path /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline/frontend/node_modules/pre-commit
[INFO] npm ERR! errno -11
[INFO] npm ERR! spawn sh EAGAIN
[INFO] npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
[INFO] 
[INFO] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[INFO] npm ERR!     /var/lib/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2022-07-22T09_11_43_478Z-debug-0.log
```

the relevant part of the log is here: https://pastebin.com/ewp6zRcv

the jenkins pipeline is:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin/(.*)', defaultValue: 'staging', name: 'BRANCH', type: 'PT_BRANCH'
    }

    tools {
        maven "Maven"
        nodejs "Node"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                // Get some code from a GitHub repository
                git branch: "${params.BRANCH}", url: 'https://github.com/TheExkaliburg/MoreFair'
             
                // Run Maven on a Unix agent.
                sh "mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true clean package"
            }

            post {
                success {
                    archiveArtifacts 'target/*.jar'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the jenkins is installed on a linux server with ubuntu 20.04 and the project itself can be found on https://github.com/TheExkaliburg/MoreFair and the branch to be built is staging

the strange thing is that EAGAIN failures are normally “Resource temporarily unavailable.” failures. running the process as root or as the jenkins user works fine without any errors, i have enough leftover disk space and my ram & cpu are never even close to getting to 100% during the build process

its also strange since the error that comes up is not always the same, f.e.

```
[INFO] -  Building for production...
[INFO] node[80787]: pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable
[INFO] node:events:505
[INFO]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[INFO]       ^
[INFO] 
[INFO] Error: spawn /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MoreFairStaging/frontend/node/node EAGAIN
[INFO]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
[INFO]     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
[INFO]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
[INFO] Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
[INFO]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
[INFO]     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
[INFO]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
[INFO]   errno: -11,
[INFO]   code: 'EAGAIN',
[INFO]   syscall: 'spawn /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MoreFairStaging/frontend/node/node',
[INFO]   path: '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MoreFairStaging/frontend/node/node',
[INFO]   spawnargs: [
[INFO]     '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MoreFairStaging/frontend/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/worker.js',
[INFO]     20
[INFO]   ]
[INFO] }
```

or

```
[7,371s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
```

the version for node are 16.16.0 and for npm 8.11; maven is on 3.8.6 with java 17 for maven and java 11 for jenkins (2.346.2)

Comment: have you checked ulimit?

Comment: yes i didn, turns out the tasklimit for the service wasn't accurate, added TasksMax=500 under [Service] to make it work

Answer (score 1):

So the problem with this specific case was that the service config didn't allow for more tasks to spawn

a simple way to fix this (after one week of recherche and trying a various amount of things) is `systemctl edit jenkins` and add to the config

```
[Service]
TaskMax=500
```

the number can vary but the default of 165 you can find out through `systemctl show --property=DefaultTasksMax` wasn't enough

Answer (score 0):

I don't konw if you fixed this error, but usually when I get this kind of EAGAIN errors, it means a probleme of resources.

You should try increase your memory limit allocated to node by using the NODE_OPTIONS var (be sure your resources supports 8Go)

```
env.NODE_OPTIONS = "--max-old-space-size=8192"

pipeline {
    agent any
    
    parameters {
        gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin/(.*)', defaultValue: 'staging', name: 'BRANCH', type: 'PT_BRANCH'
    }

    tools {
        maven "Maven"
        nodejs "Node"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                // Get some code from a GitHub repository
                git branch: "${params.BRANCH}", url: 'https://github.com/TheExkaliburg/MoreFair'
             
                // Run Maven on a Unix agent.
                sh "mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true clean package"
            }

            post {
                success {
                    archiveArtifacts 'target/*.jar'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```